# Dialogflow - Is it possible to call a Dialogflow intent using javascript from website backend?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm fairly new to Dialogflow and I'm trying to create a button on my website that will not only trigger Dialogflow Messenger to open when clicked, but also call a specific intent, instead of the default welcome intent. I have tried to update the "intent" parameter for df-messenger, but it does not work, so I am wondering if there is another way I can do this. Sorry if I use certain terms incorrectly in advance!